# Moving folders into alphabetised sub directories in unix

Tags: linux, unix, subdirectory, mv

Given a folder of company names:

```
Ace inc
Austerity
A to Z
Beeline Industries
Bing
Booze inc.
Crypto
....
Zeebra
```

...I need to move all the A* folders in to a subdirectory A:

```
A/Ace inc
A/Austerity
A/A to Z
...
```

I tried the following command: `mv A* /A/` which works up until a point, then fails because it tries to move the newly created `A/` into itself.

Further -I feel having run this command once already, I may have made a mess of our filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a list of the filenames before you begin moving. You shouldn't have been able to write to `/...` unless you were running as *SuperUser* or `root`, so you shouldn't have thrashed anything (you may very well have made a mess of the subdirectory containing the original files...)

To create a list of the files in the current directory and loop over them one-by-one, you can simply use `for fname in *; do ... done`. You will need to quote all subsequent uses of `fname` to prevent word-splitting. Since you have also tagged your question `shell` and not `bash`, etc., you will need to use a POSIX conforming way to obtain the first character (`fc`) of each filename. To do that you can use the old `expr substr "$fname" 1 1` in a command substitution, e.g.

```
    fc=$(expr substr "$fname" 1 1)  ## use 'expr substr ...' to get 1st char
```

Putting it altogether in a POSIX compliant shell script that only operates on files in the current directory moving all files in the current directory to an appropriate subdirectory based on the first character of the filename, you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh

for fname in *; do                  ## loop over each file
    [ -d "$fname" ] && continue     ## skip all directory names
    fc=$(expr substr "$fname" 1 1)  ## use 'expr substr ...' to get 1st char
    mkdir -p "$fc" || exit 1        ## create the directory or exit
    mv "$fname" "$fc" || exit 1     ## move the file or exit
done
```

**Resulting Directory Structure**

Using the filenames you provided in your example list would results in the following directory structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── A
│   ├── A to Z
│   ├── Ace inc
│   └── Austerity
├── B
│   ├── Beeline Industries
│   ├── Bing
│   └── Booze inc.
├── C
│   └── Crypto
└── Z
    └── Zeebra
```

If you need help fixing your filesystem, you will need to ask that question on the other StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as it is not "Programming" related.

If you have `bash` or some other shell that supports string-indexes as a parameter expansion, then using that to obtain the first-character will be faster and avoid the subshell needed by the command substitution with `$(expr ...)`

Let me know if you have further questions on the move of files to subdirectories.

**Edit Based on Clarification to Not Move Files in Current Directory**

OK, if we have reached the understanding that (1) you are running `bash` as your shell, (2) you do not want to move **files** in the current directory, below subdirectories, and (3) only want to move **directories** contained in the working directory (with their contents) below directories created from the first character of the directory name, you could make the following changes below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in *; do                  ## loop over each file
    [ -f "$fname" ] && continue     ## skip files in the current dir
    fc=${fname:0:1}                 ## use parameter expansion for 1st char
    mkdir -p "$fc" || exit 1        ## create the directory or exit
    [ "$fc" = "$fname" ] && continue    ## don't move dir into itself
    mv "$fname" "$fc" || exit 1     ## move the directory or exit
done
```

**Original Directory Structure**

An example with your script in the current directory and additional directories of `Apples` and `Cans` containing files that need to be moved below the `'A'` and `'C'` directories, respectively:

```
$ tree .
.
├── A
│   ├── A to Z
│   ├── Ace inc
│   └── Austerity
├── Apples
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2.3
├── B
│   ├── Beeline Industries
│   ├── Bing
│   └── Booze inc.
├── C
│   └── Crypto
├── Cans
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
├── Z
│   └── Zeebra
└── script.sh
```

**Example Use**

```
$ bash script.sh
```

**Resulting Directory Structure**

```
$ tree .
.
├── A
│   ├── A to Z
│   ├── Ace inc
│   ├── Apples
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2.3
│   └── Austerity
├── B
│   ├── Beeline Industries
│   ├── Bing
│   └── Booze inc.
├── C
│   ├── Cans
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── Crypto
├── Z
│   └── Zeebra
└── script.sh
```

Look this over and let me know if we have had a meeting-of-the-minds on what you are needing to accomplish.

Comment: Brilliant.  To be clear, `A to Z` etc are folders.  I want to move the entire `A to Z` folder into `A\A to Z\`.  I am curious about the first line inside the loop `-d`.

Comment: Oh `[ -d "$fname" ] && continue` just tests whether the name collected with `for fname in *` was a directory, and if so, it will `continue` to get the next filename skipping the rest of the loop. I am still unclear what you mean by `A\A` to `Z`. I thought you wanted to move files into subdirectories based on the first character of the filename. Are you saying you want to move the entire resulting `A` directory somewhere else? We can put it anywhere -- we just need to know where that is `:)`

Comment: I chose a terrible example folder name.  The resultant folder structure you've proved is exactly the outcome I am after.  I've had to make a small modification.  I also need to skip over folders where the folder name contains only one character.  
 
I will post and update the resultant script.

Comment: OK, I'll look for the update. I think you are saying you want to skip over single-character filenames so they do not end up in a subdirectory? Say you have a filenames `'A'` -- you need to move to a temp name before creating the directory and then moving the file to avoid the error where you want to create a directory name that already exists as a filename -- I think?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the script a little to prevent attempts to nest the folder A inside itself, and `expr` resulted in a syntax error.

```
#!/bin/sh

for fname in *; do
if [ ${#fname} -gt 1 ]; then
    fc=$(echo $fname | head -c 1)
    mkdir -p "$fc" || exit 1
    mv "$fname" "$fc" || exit 1
fi
done
```

Comment: OK, that is one way to do it. You are skipping single-character filenames in order to skip the created directories. That will work as long as you never have a single-character filename. Your use of `${#fname}` for length shows you are running more than POSIX shell (otherwise you would need `$(expr length "$fname")`). Why not use `len="${#fname}"` then `if [ "$len" -eq '1' && -f "$fname" ]` make a copy of the file, then create the directory and move the temp file back under the appropriate directory under its original single-character name?

Comment: You could also do that test with `if [ "$fc" = "$fname" ]` handle the single-character filename issue.

Comment: Ok.  So what I have is working except that it's moving the `script.sh` file into a directory named `s`.  How can I modify the script such that it will move all the directories subsequently the files contained inside them, and leave the files in the root path alone?

Comment: OK, before we get there, can you give me the output of `echo $SHELL`? That will give me a better idea of what tools to use. If there is no output, just let me know that as well. And, confirm, that if you have a directory `Apples` in the working directory, you want that directory moved under the `A` subdirectory as well?

Comment: Results of `echo $SHELL` are `/bin/bash`.  Yes your assumption is correct.  `Apples` directory should move to `A/Apples/`.

Comment: When you say *"leave the files in the root path alone"* are you saying that you only want to move directories (and the files they already contain) below `A/, B/, ...` and leave any file in the working directory as is, -- so we will not be moving any files that are not already contained in a subdirectory? So my first example was almost opposite of what you wanted to move?

Comment: This is exactly correct.  Apologies for not being clear.